# Annotating the components in a design in Altium Designer

Tags: schematics, altium

When designing a circuit in Altium, each page starts with the numbering of its components from the first. For example, I have 3 resistors on the first page: R1, R2, R3. On the second page, I have two resistors, also numbered R1, R2. I want this to be on the second page: R4, R5.

When I do this: Tools>Annotation>Annotate Schematics, this is what I get:

[image]

I have 3 sheets. How can I number the components so that they don't have the same name? I have the problem that on the first sheet I find R1, C1, and on the second sheet I find R1, C1 as well, and on the third sheet I also find R1, C1.

More specifically, how do I add the sheets in frame 1 to frame 2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need the documents collected under a project file.  **File** / **New** / **Project**, enter desired name and location, **OK**, drag files into the project.